# SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'test@abc.com'

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I am using microsoft jdbc for connecting to azure sql. Below is the java code :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;database=<my database name>;user=test@abc.com@xyz-url-dev-123abc;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");
```

Getting error `SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'test@abc.com'` (user name is changed with same format).
Is ***@*** causing problem ? Because for user parameter I am sending 'user@url' which is `test@abc.com@xyz-url-dev-123abc`
Let me know if I am making sense!

Comment: You trying to use SQL Server auth with what looks like an AAD identity.

Comment: I don't think its an AAD Identity, it seems like OP has used an email address as SA username while creating the Azure SQL server. Its been a long time so I could be totally off.  I believe @xyz-url-dev-123abc should be the same as your Azure SQL Server name. Assuming xyz-url-dev-123abc is your server instance name, the username would be test@abc.com@xyz-url-dev-123abc.database.windows.net. If that's not the case, and if its indeed an AAD Identity, let us know.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks man, I followed the document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#connect-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode

Comment: @SaiPuli Yeah man , it was AAD . Thanks btw .